# get new customers compared to last month in dax power bi

Tags: sql, excel, powerbi, dax

**Table**
i have two columns Date_Created and Customer in table

**Task**
what i want to achieve is if i select a month in slicer in power bi i want to get new customers i.e their names compared to last month.
Here i have a table called orders and this is the extracted data for June and July 2022

June

```
    +───────────────+───────────+
    | Date Created  | Customer  |
    +───────────────+───────────+
    | 02/06/2022    | A         |
    | 06/06/2022    | D         |
    | 06/06/2022    | D         |
    | 09/06/2022    | F         |
    | 14/06/2022    | B         |
    | 15/06/2022    | B         |
    | 21/06/2022    | E         |
    | 22/06/2022    | A         |
    | 22/06/2022    | C         |
    | 23/06/2022    | E         |
    | 27/06/2022    | E         |
    | 28/06/2022    | D         |
    +───────────────+───────────+
```

July

```
    +───────────────+───────────+
    | Date Created  | Customer  |
    +───────────────+───────────+
    | 04/07/2022    | G         |
    | 06/07/2022    | G         |
    | 11/07/2022    | F         |
    | 11/07/2022    | F         |
    | 12/07/2022    | D         |
    | 12/07/2022    | D         |
    | 12/07/2022    | E         |
    | 12/07/2022    | E         |
    | 13/07/2022    | H         |
    | 13/07/2022    | H         |
    | 18/07/2022    | C         |
    | 21/07/2022    | C         |
    | 25/07/2022    | C         |
    | 26/07/2022    | A         |
    | 26/07/2022    | A         |
    | 26/07/2022    | A         |
    +───────────────+───────────+
```

**Expected Result**
if i chose july 2022 in slicer i should get "G" and "H" Customer which are new customers for the month of july compared to june.
How this can be achieved in DAX?
is it also possible if this same can be also achieved using Quarters?
Please let me know if you need further information
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following **measure** assumes that your date slicer is using the auto-created *Date Hierarchy* from the `Date Created` field.

```
New Customers =
VAR ThisMonth =
    SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[Date Created].[MonthNo] )
VAR LastMonth = ThisMonth - 1
VAR CustomersThisMonth =
    DISTINCT(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            FILTER( ALL( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Date Created].[MonthNo] = ThisMonth ),
            "C1", 'Table'[Customer]
        )
    )
VAR CustomersLastMonth =
    DISTINCT(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            FILTER( ALL( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Date Created].[MonthNo] = LastMonth ),
            "C1", 'Table'[Customer]
        )
    )
VAR T1 =
    EXCEPT( CustomersThisMonth, CustomersLastMonth )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX( T1, [C1], ", " )
```

Comment: i will try this and let you know thanks

Comment: Hi Jos, what if i have to add more filter to this code? like i have a supplier column and i want to add that

Comment: and what is "C1", is it column name?

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly include a filter within the DAX for supplier, as opposed to just using a slicer for supplier? The above should react to slicers on other columns. Yes, C1 is just the name I gave to the columns I created in the temporary tables.

Comment: I tried it but using slicer with it not working, and without supplier filter i am not able to confirm if the code is working…

Comment: What i did is i included a && option in filter column and created a variable called selected supplier