# Compare Selected quarter to last quarter in DAX, even when i select Q1 it should compare with last year's Q4

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

Hi i am working on a solution in DAX where i have to find customers not ordered in current Quarter compared to its last quarter, i am able to compare Q2, Q3 and Q4 but when i select Q1 i get no value. if i select it should compare with Q4 of last year
how this can be achieved?
Thanks

this was my original question
[get new customers compared to last month in dax power bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74038989/get-new-customers-compared-to-last-month-in-dax-power-bi)

with a little bit of tinkering i am here now

```
Customers Not ordered This Quarter = 
VAR ThisQuarter =
    SELECTEDVALUE( DailyReport[DateCreated].[QuarterNo])
VAR ThisYEAR =
    SELECTEDVALUE(DailyReport[DateCreated].[Year])
VAR SelectedSupplier = 
    SELECTEDVALUE(DailyReport[SupplierName])
VAR LastQuarter = ThisQuarter - 1
VAR CustomersThisQuarter =
    DISTINCT(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            FILTER( ALL( DailyReport ), DailyReport[DateCreated].[QuarterNo] = ThisQuarter && DailyReport[SupplierName] = SelectedSupplier && DailyReport[DateCreated].[Year] = ThisYEAR),
            "C1", DailyReport[VenueName]
        )
    )
VAR CustomersLastQuarter =
    DISTINCT(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            FILTER( ALL( DailyReport ), DailyReport[DateCreated].[QuarterNo] = LastQuarter && DailyReport[SupplierName] = SelectedSupplier && DailyReport[DateCreated].[Year] = ThisYEAR),
            "C1", DailyReport[VenueName]
        )
    )
VAR T1 =
    EXCEPT(CustomersLastQuarter, CustomersThisQuarter )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX( T1, [C1], UNICHAR(10), [C1], ASC)
```

it should compare with the last year's Q4 when i select Q1 in current year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need a date table. I have written the code below blind but it should work.

```
   Customers Not ordered This Quarter = 
    VAR ThisQuarter =
        SELECTEDVALUE( DailyReport[DateCreated].[QuarterNo])
    VAR ThisYEAR =
        SELECTEDVALUE(DailyReport[DateCreated].[Year])
    VAR SelectedSupplier = 
        SELECTEDVALUE(DailyReport[SupplierName])
    VAR LastQuarter = IF(ThisQuarter = 1,4,ThisQuarter - 1)
    VAR LastYear = IF(ThisQuarter = 1,ThisYEAR -1,ThisYEAR)
    
    VAR CustomersThisQuarter =
        DISTINCT(
            SELECTCOLUMNS(
                FILTER( ALL( DailyReport ), DailyReport[DateCreated].[QuarterNo] = ThisQuarter && DailyReport[SupplierName] = SelectedSupplier && DailyReport[DateCreated].[Year] = ThisYEAR),
                "C1", DailyReport[VenueName]
            )
        )
    VAR CustomersLastQuarter =
        DISTINCT(
            SELECTCOLUMNS(
                FILTER( ALL( DailyReport ), DailyReport[DateCreated].[QuarterNo] = LastQuarter && DailyReport[SupplierName] = SelectedSupplier && DailyReport[DateCreated].[Year] = LastYEAR),
                "C1", DailyReport[VenueName]
            )
        )
    VAR T1 =
        EXCEPT(CustomersLastQuarter, CustomersThisQuarter )
    RETURN
        CONCATENATEX( T1, [C1], UNICHAR(10), [C1], ASC)
```

Comment: yup it is working, Thanks. BTW what do you mean by Date Table, how this can be achieved if i have Date table?

Comment: Power BI requires a star schema to work effectively and part of that is creating a full date table with the attributes you require. Have a read here: https://radacad.com/power-bi-date-or-calendar-table-best-method-dax-or-power-query